# how to fix the size of password input field?

Tags: html, css, textbox, passwordbox

my html code is

```
<tr>
                <td>User ID:</td>
                <td><input type="text" id="uid" size="20"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Password:</td>
                <td><input type="password" id="pass" size="20"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
```

**but the problem is, password textbox length is coming diffrent in IE, means `uid` size is `20` but `pass` size is around `17`.**

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try using `style="width:200px"` for example rather than specifying size that way.

> ```
> <input type="text" id="uid" style="width:200px;">
> <input type="password" id="pass" style="width:200px;">
> ```

Or you can create a class in the CSS like this:

```
.input{
  width:200px;
}
```

And use like this:

```
<input type="text" id="uid" class="input">
<input type="password" id="pass" class="input">
```

Answer (score 1):

You can fix it with `width: 150px;` (with CSS).

In CSS file :

```
input {
  width: 150px;
}
```

Or in inline CSS : `style="width: 150px;"` .

**Edit :** Grilled :) .